# Uniyt Photon PUN RPC is only can use in room?

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

i make a mobile game(Android) use unity5, photon PUN 1(PUN classic)
i wanna friends add !
can i use PUN RPC in Lobby? not room?

if can use lobby how use targets?

playerPrefab.GetComponent().RPC("GoBattle1", PhotonTargets.Others, GameStart);

how write PhotonTargets.??

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In PUN, clients can exchange events only when joined to rooms.
Outside of rooms, you can use [Photon Chat](https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/Chat) or another service.

Comment: thank you for answer,
Photon Chat can send message another offline player ?? 
i wanna send another player friends add !

Comment: Using Photon Chat you can send a private message to an offline user. When the user connects, the message will be received. However, if the sender disconnects before the target user connects, the message will be lost.